# Ctags on project level

Tags: vim, ctags

I am trying to setup ctags and not sure if I am doing something wrong or not. I seem to not get any dropdown's for autocomplete and in vim when I do :tags it comes up empty.

Project Structure

```
C:\Users\costa\Development\CarApplication
- CarApplication.Web
----Controllers
------DashboardController.cs
- Tags
- global.json
```

So in windows explorer I got to the CarApplication directory, right click on global.json file and say edit in vim

Vim opens up and the file is loaded. I type :tags and hit enter

[image]

Then using Ctrlp I open the DashboardController and do the same and I get the same results. Here is what is in my .vimrc

```
set tags=./.git/tags,tags;$HOME
```

I checked the tags file and there are stuff in it. This has gotten me stumped

Answer (score 2):

`:tags` shows the content of the *tag stack*. Each time you jump to a tag, that tag is added to the tag stack, you can then use `:tags` to visualize your tag history and jump to an arbitrary tag. If you didn't jump to any tag the tag stack is empty so `:tags` is useless at this point.

You can use `:echo tagfiles()` to see what `tags` files were found by Vim and `:echo taglist('.')` to display the (potentially long) list of tags found in those `tags` files.

To jump to a tag, you will need to use commands like `:tag foo` or `:tlist foo` or `<C-]>`.

See `:help tags` for the details.